# How to set a image as the background of UIView but scaled properly?

Tags: iphone

I would like the user to be able to select a image from their photos and set it to the background of the main view.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    UIImage *testimg = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSArray  * sysPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );

    filePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"%@/%@", [sysPaths objectAtIndex: 0], @"testimg.png"];
    if ( [UIImagePNGRepresentation ( testimg) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES] )    ;

    self.backgroundColor= [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePath]];


     }
```

Aside from this method being a bit sluggish in speed, this works great! There is one problem though. When the image is selected the image is not scaled properly. How would I get around this?

Thanks in advance,

-David

Comment: Also, you already have the image. File I/O on the device is really slow, so just use the image you got already instead of reading the image you just wrote out. You may also think of writing it out on another thread so that the method can return right away. The way you do it, you have to wait for the image to be compressed, written, then read again and then decompressed again, so naturally it will feel a bit sluggish :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at UIImageView in particular the contentMode property.

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: problem is i'm using a UIImage, not UIImageView and it doesent look like UIImage's have a property called contentMode...

Comment: You must be displaying the UIImage in a view though, find that view and look for the property.

Comment: So I've tried changing the content mode via code and even IB and I haven't been able to see a difference. No mater which content mode I chose I continue to see the same problem. I've been using self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

Comment: Can you add a UIImageView to your existing view and load the image into that instead of using self.background?